# How I match old and new password if I use a hash function?

Tags: php, security, password-encryption

I store user passwords as a plain text in the database. So it's easy to change the password. I use this code,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($row['Password']==$opass)
    mysql_query(
      "UPDATE information SET Password='$pass' WHERE Username='$name'"
    );
}
```

First I am checking that user put his old password correctly (`$opass`), then I allow him to change it to new password (`$pass`). I think I could check old password because I stored it as plain text. But if I use any hash algorithm, how could this `if($row['Password']==$opass)` code work? I think `$opass` and `$row['Password']` won't be same.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hash the user inputted password with the equivalent hashing function, and compare that to what you have stored in your database.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 if($row['Password']==yourOneWayPasswordHashingFunction($opass))
  mysql_query("UPDATE information SET Password='$pass' WHERE Username='$name'");}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, use [`bcrypt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Passwords can be hard, so use this, and then go shopping, in time for xmas too :)

Also...

> I store user passwords as a plain text in the database. **So it's easy to change the password**.

<sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

You should never store plain text passwords, and *it's easy to change* is not a valid reason. Kudos, however, for recognising the need to do something about it.

Comment: Could you write some line of code for me? I just need to see the concept.

Comment: @user1902462 Sure, I wrapped your `$opass` variable with a function, that you will need to write. It might be good to have it wrap a [`bcrypt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) implementation for PHP.

Comment: Well that check will only work with a bad (unsalted) hashing function ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster It may build a salt from the password ;)